# SSRS - multiple timesheet reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I currently have a Timesheet Report, which uses the single **TimesheetID**. However, I am now looking at saving some time for the staff, by grouping Timesheets together by the **WeekEnding** date, and from this, im hoping to populate each individual page into one report. So for example Joe Bloggs on page 1, Steve Jobs on page 2 and so on.... as a rule, the Timesheet has never exceeded 1 page in length.

I have created a new report call GroupTimesheet. and added a dataset called General, which contains information:

```
SELECT 
StaffTable.Staffname,
Timesheet.WeekEnding
FROM Timesheet
INNER JOIN StaffTable ON Timesheet.StaffID = StaffTable.StaffID
WHERE Timesheet.WeekEnding = @WeekEnding
```

***Its what to do next im struggling with***. I have this query below which contains the Timesheet lines, but is still referencing the **TimesheetID**. If I change this to **WeekEnding** ONLY, it shows all the TimesheetLines for all staff, not per TimesheetID:

```
SELECT
TimesheetLine.LineDate,
TimesheetLine.StartTime,
TimesheetLine.FinishTime
FROM TimesheetLine
INNER JOIN Timesheet ON TimesheetLine.TimesheetID = Timesheet.TimesheetID
WHERE Timesheet.TimesheetID = @TimesheetID
AND Timesheet.WeekEnding = @WeekEnding
```

**How would I set up a report to achieve my goal?**

This is the current Database Design I am using, with sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Timesheet (TimesheetID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
WeekEnding DATE,
StaffID INT)

CREATE TABLE StaffTable (StaffID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
Staffname VARCHAR(50))

CREATE TABLE TimesheetLine (TimesheetLineID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
TimesheetID INT,
LineDate DATE,
StartTime VARCHAR(5),
FinishTime VARCHAR(5))

ALTER TABLE Timesheet ADD CONSTRAINT TimesheetID_PK PRIMARY KEY (TimesheetID)
ALTER TABLE StaffTable ADD CONSTRAINT StaffID_PK PRIMARY KEY (StaffID)
ALTER TABLE TimesheetLine ADD CONSTRAINT TimesheetLineID_PK PRIMARY KEY (TimesheetLineID)

ALTER TABLE Timesheet ADD CONSTRAINT StaffID_T2ST FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES StaffTable (StaffID)
ALTER TABLE TimesheetLine ADD CONSTRAINT TimesheetID_TL2T FOREIGN KEY (TimesheetID) REFERENCES Timesheet (TimesheetID)

--DATA
INSERT INTO StaffTable VALUES ('Joe Bloggs')
INSERT INTO StaffTable VALUES ('Steve Jobs')

INSERT INTO Timesheet VALUES ('2017-07-23', 1)
INSERT INTO Timesheet VALUES ('2017-07-23', 2)

INSERT INTO TimesheetLine VALUES (1, '2017-07-17', '09:00', '17:30')
INSERT INTO TimesheetLine VALUES (1, '2017-07-18', '09:00', '17:30')
INSERT INTO TimesheetLine VALUES (1, '2017-07-19', '09:00', '17:30')
INSERT INTO TimesheetLine VALUES (1, '2017-07-20', '09:00', '17:30')
INSERT INTO TimesheetLine VALUES (1, '2017-07-21', '09:00', '17:30')

INSERT INTO TimesheetLine VALUES (2, '2017-07-17', '08:00', '17:00')
INSERT INTO TimesheetLine VALUES (2, '2017-07-18', '08:00', '17:00')
INSERT INTO TimesheetLine VALUES (2, '2017-07-19', '08:00', '17:00')
INSERT INTO TimesheetLine VALUES (2, '2017-07-20', '08:00', '17:00')
INSERT INTO TimesheetLine VALUES (2, '2017-07-21', '08:00', '17:00')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a report that can output a single timesheet correctly then you don't have much work to do. We can use this report as a subreport.

Create a new report.
Add a dataset 'dsTimesheets' with the query as `SELECT TimeSheetID FROM Timesheet WHERE Weekending = @WeekEnding`

Add a simple table/tablix with one column, one row and set it's dataset to `dsTimesheets`, this will act as our loop. In the tablix cell, insert a subreport and set the parameter of the subreport to `TimesheetID`. You'll want to stretch the cell so it fits the width of the report I guess too.

At this point the report should work as long as you have a couple of entries per weeknding value (your sample data only has one).

Once you have tested this you can finish off by right clicking the row group and setting the page break properties to 'between...'.

You could also change the `dsTimesheets` query to join to your staff table so you can order the timesheets by staff name ect.

Comment: that worked brilliantly, I didn't know you could add a sub report within a table!! thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1):

Wherever possible, it's easiest for your SSRS report design to have a single SQL query for the data source that has all the data you need.

> If I change this to WeekEnding ONLY, it shows all the TimesheetLines for all staff

This sounds like what you're aiming for - a report where you input just a date parameter, and it gives all the relevant timesheets for all staff. If you **join all three tables** together, you can see which staff relate to which timesheet lines:

```
SELECT
    StaffTable.StaffID,
    StaffTable.StaffName,
    Timesheet.TimesheetID,
    Timesheet.WeekEnding,
    TimesheetLine.TimesheetLineID,
    TimesheetLine.LineDate,
    TimesheetLine.StartTime,
    TimesheetLine.FinishTime
FROM
    StaffTable
    INNER JOIN Timesheet ON StaffTable.StaffID = Timesheet.StaffID
    INNER JOIN TimesheetLine ON Timesheet.TimesheetID = TimesheetLine.TimesheetID
WHERE
    Timesheet.WeekEnding = @WeekEnding
```

With this you can set up your report with a table or list, and **group it by both `StaffID` and `TimesheetID`** (in case of staff with multiple timesheets in the same week). You'll probably also want to set the Page Breaks in the grouping, to be 'Between each instance of a group'.